# The method setText(String) in the type JLabel is not applicable for the arguments(File)

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am trying to place the path for the folder chosen in the label but it will not convert a File to a String.

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {
                    JFileChooser filechooser;
                    String choosertitle = null;

```
                filechooser = new JFileChooser(); 
                filechooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
                filechooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
                filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                //
                // disable the "All files" option.
                //
                filechooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                //    

                int returnValue = filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " 
                            +  filechooser.getCurrentDirectory());
                    lbl_Arborescence.setText(filechooser.getCurrentDirectory());
                    System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " 
                            +  filechooser.getSelectedFile());                  
                }
        }
```

Comment: lbl_Arborescence.setText(filechooser.getCurrentDirectory());   is my issue.

Comment: Use `File#getPath()`

Answer (score 1):

JFileChooser.getCurrentDirectory() returns a File object. You want to get the name of that file. Use something like

```
lbl_Arborescence.setText(fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath());
```

[See Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName())

Answer (score 0):

`JLabel#setText` requires a `String` parameter, obviously, `File` is not a `String` type.

You can use `File#getPath` to return the `String` representation of the path instead

```
lbl_Arborescence.setText(filechooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath());
```